# Confidence intervals - inconsistent results with different methods

Tags: r, statistics, confidence-interval

I encountered an interesting phenomenon while calculating confidence intervals. I will try to replicate the problem with generation a set of numbers with normal distribution.

I used two methods to calculate confidence intervals, however, each yielded different results.

```
## Generating a normal distribution
set.seed(1)
p <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000))

## Method no. 1 for calculating CI.
p %>%
  summarize(
    lower = 0 - 2 * sd(x),
    upper = 0 + 2 * sd(x)
  )

## Method no. 2 for calc. CI.
p %>%
  summarize(
    lower = quantile(x, p = 0.025),
    upper = quantile(x, p = 0.975)
  )
```

First method gives 95% CI <-2.069832, 2.069832> and second gives <-2.130874, 2.006109>

Any ideas why are results different. I expected to see the same result.

Comment: Why would you expect to see the same result? There's going to be some small difference between CI and sample quantiles. I'm thinking you could compare [-1.96, 1.96] to 0  ± `sd(x)` to `mean(x)` ± `sd(x)` to `quantile(x, p = c(0.025, 0.975))`. These will be different, but the difference approaches 0 as n becomes arbitrarily large

Comment: When you have finite n, these will just not be exactly equal. Especially not with "just" 1000. Doing this on my machine with n = 100 million finally gets the difference to less than 0.001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2` is a rule of thumb to construct confidence intervals, not the true value that is closer to 1.95. Use that in the first method:

```r
## Method no. 1 for calculating CI.
p %>%
    summarize(
        lower = 0 - qnorm(0.975) * sd(x),
        upper = 0 + qnorm(0.975) * sd(x)
    )
```

Values will be closer

Answer (score -1):

use another `set.seed`, instead of 1000 try to take 1000000

```
set.seed(2)
p <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000000))
sd(p$x)
mean(p$x)
## Method no. 1 for calculating CI.
p %>%
  summarize(
    lower = 0 - qnorm(p = 0.975) * sd(x),
    upper = 0 + qnorm(p = 0.975) * sd(x)
  )

## Method no. 2 for calc. CI.
p %>%
  summarize(
    lower = quantile(x, p = 0.025),
    upper = quantile(x, p = 0.975)
  )
```